# Doctrine workround for late row lookups (straight join) (super slow orderBy)

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I have a configered Doctrine QueryBuilder which I use to create a list for an API response.
This list have a variable amount of `JOIN` and `WHERE`, depending on what the user has filtered/searched.

This query takes about 1sec without sorting, 10+sec with sorting, which is too slow.
In SQL I did this (I believe this is called a *straight join*), this fixes the issue:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    the-actual-build-query
)
ORDER BY delivery_date ASC
LIMIT 35
```

However, I'm not using SQL, but Doctrine QueryBuilder. But I cant figure out how to make Doctrine do the same thing.
Because I'm working with a prepared statement, I cant just build the query and wrap it, I need to do something with the parameters. But those are various types, I cant get a working elegant solution.

Does anyone have a working solution?

---

### (some of) my attempts

```php
public function setSorting(QueryBuilder $qb): QueryBuilder
    {
        $stmt = $qb->getEntityManager()
            ->getConnection()
            ->prepare('SELECT * FROM (' . $qb->getQuery()->getSQL() . ') result');

        foreach ($qb->getParameters() as $param) {
            $stmt->bindValue(
                $param->getName(),
                $param->getValue(),
                $param->getType() // <-- this fails on a binary uuid array
            );
        }
       
        $result = $stmt->executeQuery();

        return $finalQb;
    }
```

I am fine with an SQL only solution. I prefer to stay away from custom param convertion/binding (no, I'm not happy with my own solution).

```php
// What I would like (pseudo code):
$newQB = createQueryBuilder();
$newQB
    ->addSelect('*') // or ->addSelect('inner')
    ->from($innerQb, 'inner')
    ->orderBy(inner.deliveryDate);
```

But neither the `from` or `addSelect` are valid.

```php
$query = $qb->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT X FROM (' . $qb . ') as X')
    ->setMaxResults(10);
// "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'FROM (SELECT': Error: Subquery is not supported here",
```

**I am also very fine with another solution!**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was very close. The issue was mostly that I couldn't get the UUID parameters to work. I have a little workaround for that, now I have a working solution:

```php
public function setSorting(QueryBuilder $qb)
{
    $connection = $qb->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM (' . $qb->getQuery()->getSQL() . ') wrapper ');

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($qb->getParameters() as $param) {
       $stmt->bindValue(
            $i++,  // Doctrine has turned everything in a ?, we need to use index reference
            $param->getValue(),
            $param->getType()
        );
    }

    return $stmt->executeQuery();
}
```

That was working, apart from the `uuid[]` selectors (Eg `WHERE uuid IN(?)`).
The solution (specific for my case, but you can get the jist of it):

```php
$qb->andWhere('example.uuid IN(:example_0, :example_1, :example_2)');
$qb->setParameter('example_0', $uuids[0], UuidBinaryOrderedTimeType::NAME);
$qb->setParameter('example_1', $uuids[1], UuidBinaryOrderedTimeType::NAME);
$qb->setParameter('example_2', $uuids[2], UuidBinaryOrderedTimeType::NAME);
```

*(I did this via a loop, but this made a more simple example)*